# Notepad++ delete every line starting with 02

Tags: list, csv, notepad++, filtering

I am a complete beginner so please bear with me. I have a file that contains 11k lines and I need to delete every line that starts with 02.

The file looks like this:

0206902530752013000004

020690253075201400000442526

010430050265VAN DE MH

020430050265201400

010430050360NLA COMMUNITY L

Every line that starts with 01 contains and address and name. Those are the lines that I need in my document.

Is there a way to do this in Notepad++?

Thanks so much for your help!
Michael

Answer (score 1):

Replace with regex

```
^02.*$
```

by nothing

Comment: Perfect! Thanks much!